# WebMatrix and LightBox don't appear to be pulling correct Image

Tags: thumbnails, webmatrix, lightbox2

I am new to coding and playing around with the Bakery template in WebMatrix.  I have implemented LightBox, and it seems to be working, however, it doesn't seem to be pulling the correct image.  On my page, I have thumbnails displayed on the screen.  When you click, I am trying to open the 'non-Thumbnail' sized pictures to you can see more detail.  However, it still looks like the Thumbnail size.  I have a File Directory structure for my pictures of ~\Images\Products This is where the large images reside.  Then I have ~\Images\Products\Thumbnails for the small images.  Here is my code where I am displaying the LightBox.

```
 <a href="~/Images/Products/@p.ImageName" data-lightbox="Images" title="@p.Name">
    <img class="product-image" src="~/Images/Products/@p.ImageName" />
 </a>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for the Bakery template, that I have suggested to you in the previous question deleted by you was

```
@foreach (var p in products) {
  <li class="product">
    <a href="~/Images/Products/@p.ImageName" data-lightbox="Images" title="@p.Name">
      <img class="product-image" src="~/Images/Products/Thumbnails/@p.ImageName" />
    </a>
  </li>
}
```

It works fine for me.

In future don't erase your question with an answer, but add a comment.

**Edited**

Try this:

- download from the [Lightbox 2 site](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) Lightbox v2.6
- in Webmatrix 3 create a new site from the Bakery template
- copy lightbox-2.6.min.js from the js folder of your Lightbox download into the Scripts folder of your new site
- copy lightbox.css from the css folder of your Lightbox download into the Content folder of your new site
- create a new img folder in the root of your new site and copy into it close.png, loading.gif, prev.png, and next.png from the img folder of your Lightbox download
- modify as follows the head section of the _SiteLayout.cshtml of your new site

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Fourth Coffee - @Page.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

- replace the Default.cshtml content of your new site with

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Home";

    var db = Database.Open("bakery");
    var products = db.Query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS").ToList();
}

<h1>Welcome to Fourth Coffee!</h1>

<div id="productsWrapper">
    <ul id="products" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        @foreach (var p in products) {
            <li class="product">
                <a href="~/Images/Products/@p.ImageName" data-lightbox="Images" title="@p.Name">
                    <img class="product-image" src="~/Images/Products/Thumbnails/@p.ImageName" alt="Image of @p.Name" />
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, if you run your new site you should see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that originally Thanks for your suggestion.  I like how the LightBox goes through my images with your fix.  However, it isn't pulling in the full-size image, it only pops with the Thumbnail size.  The code I listed was your code, I had tried with the Thumbnails in the path, and then removed it.  Both with the same results.

Comment: Sorry, about deleting the original thread.  Just didn't want my new issue to get lost in all of the detail.